# Angular Upload Progress Function Not Working as Expected

Tags: angular, file-upload, upload, progress-bar

I'm doing simple file upload function using angular and file uploading successfully.the issue is i want to update progress bar also while it uploading.below is my upload function

```
this.http.put(URL.toString(),file,
                {
                  reportProgress: true,
                  observe: 'events',
                  headers:{'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"} ,
                }).
                subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>)=> {
                   if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
                    {
                      console.log("Progress : " + Math.round((event.loaded/event.total)*100));
                      this.zone.run(() => {
                        this.uploadprogress = Math.round((event.loaded/event.total))*100;
                      });
                      this.fileadded = true;
                    }

                });
```

Here is my Progress bar code

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="uploadprogress"></mat-progress-bar>
```

so the weird this is my console is updating as expected. but progress bar is not updating correctly. when console is around 40 it start filling and then console value is around 58-60 progressbar complete . then all other functions start processing like `this.fileadded = true;`

but uploading is still progress according to the console. can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here[image]